# Bootstrap image right center corner using css absolute

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am trying to make the content and image half / align using Bootstrap col-md-6 to separate them. This is hard to me to explain so I included an image here is something looks like this:

[image]

Basically is the image full width to the corner right. And the text on the left. I have tried to put the image to col-md-6 into the same container but it looks like the image is not positioning to the corner, but when I separated it, it looks fine to the corner but it doesn't responsive. The image will cover the content/text.

I am trying to make this using Bootstrap way but also would like to learn it from using pure CSS way. Feel free include your answers here so that people can benefit it.

```css
img.img-responsive.img-absolute {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -250px;
    max-height: 650px;
    width: 650px;
}

#center {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Meet Our Best Agents</h1>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Image should include at here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="center">
    <img class="img-responsive img-absolute" src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/000/fff">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Meet Our Best Agents</h1>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Image should include at here -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="center">
                <img class="img-responsive img-absolute" src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/000/fff">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your code..

```
<link 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" 
type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script 
src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
type="text/javascript" ></script>




 <div class="col-lg-12 row">

 <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, 
    like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 
    heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, 
    which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, 
    my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere 
    tranquil 
    existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of 
    drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that 
    I 
    never was a greater artist than now.</p>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button</button>
 </div>


 <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img class="img-responsive img-absolute" 
 src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/000/fff">
  </div>


 </div>
```

this will be solved your problem. But, you have to make some CSS work in here. Your col-lg-12 or col-md-12 problem will be solved.if you had any css doubts in this code. comment below.